# Find the Laurent Series, the residue and the valid region of the following complex function:

Tags: residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have to find the Laurent-Series of the following function:

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin({\frac1{iz^3}})}{z^2} $$ in  $$z_0=0$$

My approach:

Using: $$ \sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} {z^{2n+1}} $$

$$f(z) = \frac{\sin({\frac1{iz^3}})}{z^2} = \frac{\sin({\frac{-i}{z^3}})}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} {(-iz)^{-6n-5}} $$

I can't visualize the residue (coeffincent ${c_{-1}}$) and I have no idea how to find the valid region.

Thank you.

Comment: your calculation for the Laurant expansion looks good.  Maybe the Residue is zero.  Also as a note: this function has an essential singularity at the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What's about the valid region?

Comment: Note that $(-1)^n(-\mathrm i)^{-6n-5}=\mathrm i$.

Comment: Maybe the valid region is $\mathbb{C} $ except 0

Answer (score 1):

The Laurent series is sum from n=0 To infinity of (-1)^n /(2n+1)! * 1/i^2n+1 * 1/z^6n+5. The residues is when 6n+5=1 Which is never for integer n, so the residue is 0.

Comment: ok, thank you. Is the valid region $\mathbb{C}$ except 0?